# PHP mail Function with attechment is Displaying Content type headers in Body

Tags: php, email

As I describe in Title, When I tried to send mail From php mail() function with Attachment, It Also Display Content-Type in Body.

Below Is My Code ::

```
$file_tmp_name    = $files['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name        = $files['file']['name'];
$file_size        = $files['file']['size'];
$file_type        = $files['file']['type'];
$file_error       = $files['file']['error'];

$handle = fopen($uploaded_file_path, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$boundary = md5("somestring");

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: mail@website.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = \"$boundary\"\r\n\r\n";

//plain text
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body.= "My Body Content

Regards
Team Web.\r\n\r\n";

$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";

//attachment
$body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
$body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
$body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $encoded_content;

$sentMail = @mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

[Take A look How it Display in Mail Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIOu0.png)